# Azure VM's external IP does not match DNS

Tags: azure, dns, msdn

I have an MSDN account and created a VM (Windows 2012 R2) to which I have added several software packages for a proof of concept.

The problem is that with my limited $50/month credit, I'm forced to shutdown the VM at night, especially over weekends. When you shutdown a VM from the admin console (the only way they stop charging you) you will also lose the IP address.

The problem occurs when you restart the VM the next day, it will get a different IP. If you try to lookup the machine through a ping, their advertised external IP retrieved through DNS does NOT match the external IP address of the VM.

This makes it impossible for the software to resolve the host.

I figured it might take a couple hours for DNS to push the change, but it's been all day now and the DNS address is still incorrect.

Anyone else run into this?

(I cant create a support ticket because I only have an MSDN subscription.)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you looking up the IP address? When you shutdown the machine and restart it you are correct in that it assigns a new external ip address. This only happens if this is the only VM running in that cloud service. This sounds like your setup.

The IP address you should be looking for is the one attached to the cloud service that your VM is a part of. If you go to the dashboard of the cloud service it will show you the public virtual IP address along with the FQDN. This IP will also match your VM's public IP.

See below
[image]

Comment: Joe - yes, I was using the 'public ip.' I had access to another VM in the cloud (on another account) and even the internal address would not respond. The dashboard told me it was up. I even rebooted it several times thinking something got stuck. In the end, I had to delete the machine and start over. I think their DNS/DHCP has some serious issues, but they won't fix them since none of us MSDN types can even tell them about it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest is to use Reserved IP option. It allows you to hook up semi permanent IP address to your cloud service.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

Worth mentioning that Public IP may be returned back to the pool under certain circumstances, i.e. if your subscription run out of money. This is public cloud service after all, and however big the pool is, it is still limited.

Worth noting that I'm using the same approach shutting down my VMs when I'm not using them, but I don't experience IP change too often. Possibly because I have A0 domain controller VM always running.

Comment: That's worth looking into b0rg. However, I gave up and deleted the machine since no amount of rebooting or configuring could get the machine to respond. Another developer here at work said they ran into the same problem and just deleted the machine and started over. That's what I ended up doing. Glad it's just testing.